# Silently send command to comint without printing prompt

Tags: shell, emacs, comint-mode

I want to send a command to a comint `shell-mode` without it printing an additional prompt. I'm trying to use the `comint-redirect-*` API, but I am still getting an additional prompt. What would be an easy way to either avoid the prompt printing altogether, or to track back and delete it?

My redirect,

```
(defun my-comint-redirect-silently (proc string)
  (let (comint-redirect-perform-sanity-check)
    (with-temp-buffer
      ;; possible to have shell not print prompt?
      (comint-redirect-send-command-to-process
       string (current-buffer) proc nil 'no-display)))
  (with-current-buffer (process-buffer proc)
    ;; necessary to track back and delete here?
    (comint-redirect-cleanup)))
```

Example of a call in a shell-hook,

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (my-comint-redirect-silently
             (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)) "TERM=xterm-256color")))
```

But, the comint shell then prints the following (notice the double prompt)

```
me@me-M51AC: ~
$ me@me-M51AC: ~ 
$
```

Not directly relevant, but to show it is printing twice, the prompt here is set as

```
$ echo $PS1
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[32m\]\u@\h: \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$
```

Comment: side note: If i `edebug` the `my-comint-redirect-silently` and start a shell the prompt only prints once

Comment: I think you are interested in things like `comint-send-string`, `comint-send-input`, and the like ....  For advanced stuff, see also `process-send-string`.

Comment: @lawlist well not really, I am trying to temporarily redirect the output, hence the "silently". I already have a generic inferior process redirect library, similar to `ess`'s silent redirect, but I would rather use the new(?) comint one.

Comment: err not new, I see in the git log mentions of it back to 1999

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took at look at how [comint-redirect-results-list-from-process](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/comint.el#L3802) worked and bodged this.

```
(defun comint-run-thing-process (process command)
  "Send COMMAND to PROCESS."
  (let ((output-buffer " *Comint Redirect Work Buffer*"))
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create output-buffer)
      (erase-buffer)
      (comint-redirect-send-command-to-process command
                                               output-buffer process nil t)
      ;; Wait for the process to complete
      (set-buffer (process-buffer process))
      (while (and (null comint-redirect-completed)
                  (accept-process-output process)))
      ;; Collect the output
      (set-buffer output-buffer)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      ;; Skip past the command, if it was echoed
      (and (looking-at command)
           (forward-line))
      ;; Grab the rest of the buffer
      (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) (- (point-max) 1)))))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks a lot, I was missing `accept-process-output`. I didn't actually need the redirected output for my scenario, but this cleared it up for me.